# error - order by must appear inthe list of statements contains a union,intersect or except operator

Tags: sql-server, order-by

In sql i want to add 'All' in the list for that

I  used the following code :

```
select 'all' as stateid,'all' as statename 
union 
select stateid,statename 
from state 
order by stateshortname
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using SQL Server, following should work

```
select 'all' as stateid,'all' as statename, 'all' as stateshortname
union all
select cast(stateid as varchar(16)), statename, stateshortname
from state 
order by stateshortname
```

A minor performance optimization in this cas is to use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`. Using a union essentially does a distinct, forcing the engine to find duplicate values even when there are none.

Comment: Why the `cast(stateid as varchar(16))`? What is the type of stateid`?

Comment: I assume integer. I have no SQL Server at hand to try but should there be an implicit conversion?

Comment: state id is int